# How to derive from class template

Tags: c++

I was reading book on template and found below example which highlights use of template keyword. I 
tried below example but it gives error

expected template name before < token
class D : public shell::template In::template Deep
                                       ^

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class shell {
public:
  template<int N>
  class in {
     public :
         template <int M>
         class Deep {
             public:
                 virtual void f() { cout << endl << "NO" << endl; }
         };
      };
    };



template <typename T, int N>
class weird
{
    public:
        void case1(typename shell<T>::template In<N>::template Deep<N>* n)
        {
           class D : public shell<void>::template In<N>::template Deep<N>
           {
               public :
               virtual void f() { cout << endl << "N" << endl;}
            };
            n = new D(); 
            n-> f();
         }
 };

int main() {
    weird<void,1> obj;
    obj.case1(NULL);
return 0;
}
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: Which one is line 26?

Comment: `class in` -> `class In`, everything else is correct

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong case on one of your classes:

```
void case1(typename shell<T>::template In<N>::template Deep<N>* n)
//                                     ^^^^^
```

Should be:

```
void case1(typename shell<T>::template in<N>::template Deep<N>* n)
```

Everything else is fine.